# Code output in single line?

Tags: ruby

How can I get output on a single line? Right now the name is on the first line and age comes in the next line.

I am using `print` instead of `puts` but still NOT getting the right output.

Ruby Code:

```
print "Please enter your name: ";
name = gets;

print "Please enter your age: ";
age = gets;
print "Entered details are: ",name, age;
```

Running it:

```
O/P:
Please enter your name: Tony Stark
Please enter your age: 35
Entered details are: Tony Stark
35
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `#chomp` method

```
name = gets.chomp # instead of name = gets
age = gets.chomp # instead of age = gets
```

I rewrite the code :

```
print "Please enter your name: "
name = gets.chomp

print "Please enter your age: "
age = gets.chomp
print "Entered details are: ",name, " ", age, "\n"
```

and ran it :

```
[arup@Ruby]$ ruby a.rb
Please enter your name: arup
Please enter your age: 27
Entered details are: arup 27
[arup@Ruby]$
```

[`#chomp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-chomp)

> Returns a new String with the given record separator removed from the end of str (if present). If $/ has not been changed from the default Ruby record separator, then chomp also removes carriage return characters (that is it will remove \n, \r, and \r\n).

[`#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-gets)

> Returns (and **assigns to `$_`**) the next line from the list of files in ARGV (or $*), or from standard input if no files are present on the command line.

Comment: Good answer. I could add that the separator (new line character) is added to the end of the string, because you press the Enter when you answer for the questions.

Comment: @Archetylator You could add it to my answer too.. :)